# how to add view to new activity in ViewGroup

Tags: android, button, view, android-activity, viewgroup

ok so im trying to add a button/view to a new activity other than the one the Viewgroup is already in.
here is my code so far:

Src:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    Button btn, btn1;
    LayoutInflater linflater;
    LinearLayout l;
    static int pos = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button  ButtonBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dynamicoption);
        ButtonBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

              public void onClick(View v) {
                  // Perform action on click

                startActivity(new Intent("com.nour.ImamKhomeini.DYNAMICOPTION"));


              }

          });

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);

        l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
        linflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              View myView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamicoption, l, true);
              myView.setId(pos);
              pos++;
          }
        });

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
        linflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new myListener());
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new myListener1());
    }

    class myListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View myView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamicoption, null);
            myView.setId(pos);
            pos++;
            l.addView(myView);
        }
    }

    class myListener1 implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (pos != 0) {
                pos--;
                View myView = l.findViewById(pos);
                l.removeView(myView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here are my xmls:

Main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="45dip" android:layout_width="45dip"></Button>

    <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="45dip" android:layout_width="45dip"></Button>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

dynamicoption.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:text="@+id/EditText01" android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any Help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: As a note to post code here: highlight the code and press Crtl+K to format it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a couple changes. Look how I create OnClickListener, you don't need to create a new subclass. And notice how I use the layout inflater:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View myView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamicoption, l, true);
        myView.setId(pos);
        pos++;
    }
});
```

---

Also when XML opening and closing tags don't have anything in between them:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/EditText01" ></EditText>
```

You can use the `/>` shorthand and save yourself some typing

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/EditText01" />
```

---

Here is what your onCreate() method should look like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button ButtonBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dynamicoption);
    ButtonBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            startActivity(new Intent("com.nour.ImamKhomeini.DYNAMICOPTION"));
        }
    });

    l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);
    linflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View myView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamicoption, l, true);
            myView.setId(pos);
            pos++;
        }
    });

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (pos > 0) {
                pos--;
                l.removeView(l.findViewById(pos));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are calling `btn.setOnClickListener(...)` twice, the second time you call it erases the OnClickListener I created. Simply remove the last six lines of you onCreate() method. (Also you should rewrite `btn1`'s OnClickListener like `btn`'s new listener.)

Comment: could revise the entire Java file and paste it?, thanks and sorry

Comment: Ok, hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Damn it still doesnt work!!, i dont know whats wrong, but thanks for the help, maybe you can make an example project?

Comment: Hmm, are you getting errors? If so please post the LogCat in your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15680/discussion-between-moussa-and-sam)

Comment: im not getting errors, just when i run it and tap the button it doesnt create a new button in the other activity, could  you please make a sample project?